# CQLSH is not recognized in google cloud datastax cluster nodes

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-platform, datastax, cqlsh

I have deployed a 4 node datastax cluster in GCP. I can ssh into each of the VM nodes but cqlsh is not recognized.Can you please help me to understand where I am going wrong

error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', 
    {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1',
    9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Answer (score 1):

If your cluster is working correctly, then the nodes must know about each other by their own IPs (internal or external).  So Cassandra isn't configured to bind 9042 to 127.0.0.1, which means trying to cqlsh to 127.0.0.1:9042 won't work.

One way to check, would be just to do a `nodetool status`, and use one of those IP addresses.  But, as you're on GCP, you may have both internal and external IP addresses, so in that case it really depends on which IP is set as your `broadcast_rpc_address`.  You can check them all by grepping your cassandra.yaml.

```
$ grep "_address:" cassandra.yaml 

listen_address: 192.168.1.3 
broadcast_address: 10.20.15.1
# listen_on_broadcast_address: false
rpc_address: 192.168.1.3 
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.20.15.1
```

In this case, your cqlsh command would look something like this:

```
cqlsh 10.20.15.1 -u youruser -p yourpassword
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out time to reply. I have a doubt..when you are telling Cassnadra isn't configured to bind 9042 to 127.0.0.1..I am not configuring anything on my own..its a simple datastax Cassandra cluster deployed in GCP. Did i missed any manual step while deploying apart from the standard create cluster option in GCP?

Comment: Are you using a special DataStax account or tool with GCP?  I've never seen a "create cluster" option.  In any case, all Cassandra installations have 127.0.0.1 as the default value for all of the `_address` properties I listed above.  This works for local or single-instance deployments, but **must** be changed for a plural node configuration.  So even it you didn't configure anything specifically, *something* did, or your nodes wouldn't join the cluster.  Regardless, using 127.0.0.1 will never work for a cluster with more than 1 node. @AniruddhyaDutta

Comment: yes Aron I am using DataStax service within GCP.When you launch datastax below is the default cluster option you get which you can deploy

Comment: I am not able to upload the screen shot for some reason..but if you search datastax in GCP you can easily see the default launch option.I saw a 96 node deloyment in a youtube vedio where after deployment they just tyoed cqlsh in one of the node and it worked..dont know what they did before hand.