# Not able to login to cqlsh in datastax Cassandra cluster hosted in Google cloud platform

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-platform, datastax, cqlsh

I have set up a  2 node  Casandra cluster in GCP.

[image]

But the issue is I am not able go to cqlsh.I am getting the belwo error[image]

Comment: Please paste error messages as text, not as a picture.

Comment: error message:aniruddhya_dutta@datastax-enterprise-1-us-west1-a-1-vm:~$ cqlsh 10.138.0.3
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.138.0.3': AuthenticationFailed('Remote end requires aut
hentication',)})

Comment: So about your two node cluster...  Your `nodetool status` is showing that there is only one node (10.138.0.3) in the cluster.  While 10.138.0.2 is up (from the first image), but it clearly has not joined.

Comment: Thnaks a lot @Aron ..finally I was able to connect aniruddhya_dutta@datastax-enterprise-3-us-west1-a-1-vm:~$ cqlsh 10.138.0.3 -u cassandra -p cassandra
Connected to clusters-datastax at 10.138.0.3:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.1.2070 | DSE 5.1.6 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cassandra@cqlsh>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1':
```

First, as I mentioned to you [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335666/cqlsh-is-not-recognized-in-google-cloud-datastax-cluster-nodes/50335903#50335903), using cqlsh to connect to 127.0.0.1 simply will not work in a multi-node cluster.  You will need to specify the IP address shown in the result of your `nodetool status` command.

Next, the second part of the error message should give a big clue on this one:

```
    AuthenticationFailed('Remote end requires authentication'),)})
```

With authentication enabled, you will need to provide a valid username and password to log in.  If you have not created any new users, then the username and password will both be defaulted to "cassandra."

```
$ cqlsh 10.138.0.3 -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

Comment: Hi aron..seems like I am giving wrong credentials aniruddhya_dutta@datastax-enterprise-2-asia-northeast1-a-1-vm:~$  cqlsh 10.146.0.2 -u cassandra -p cassandra
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.146.0.2': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate 
to 10.146.0.2: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Failed to login. Please re-try."',)})

Comment: @AniruddhyaDutta So it sounds like the default cassandra password has been changed, and there has been a different user created for you.  You should use *that* username and password instead.

Comment: This was really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cqlsh 10.138.0.3 9042
```

Comment: I am still getting the authentication error as below aniruddhya_dutta@datastax-enterprise-1-us-west1-a-1-vm:~$ cqlsh 10.138.0.3 9042
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.138.0.3': AuthenticationFailed('Remote end requires aut
hentication',)})

Comment: It means you have enabled Authentication and Authorization, please follow the way Aaron suggestion. It should help you out.

Comment: Hi Payal...I am still getting auth error' aniruddhya_dutta@datastax-enterprise-2-asia-northeast1-a-1-vm:~$  cqlsh 10.146.0.2 -u cassandra -p cassandra
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.146.0.2': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate 
to 10.146.0.2: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Failed to login. Please re-try."',)})

Comment: Did you create any other user before ?

Comment: Do you have 2 node cluster ? your image shows only 1 node.

Comment: I have not created any user.  I have 4 nodes which I created later.(the latest error message )

Comment: Hi @Payal..fianlly I am able to connect..Thanks a lot for your suggestions!!